# Increasing height of UIView.frame programmatically works till iPhone 8 plus but doesn't works beyond model iphone x

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am increasing the height for UIView programmatically in runtime on click of button, it works fine on iPhone 6,7,8 and plus models but doesn't works on iPhone X and beyond models. i have initially set constraints programmatically as i views are autoLayout based. I also tried to set constraints at runtime which didn't helped too.

```
//Tried this and working till iPhone 8+
self.view.frame.size.height += CGFloat(280)
//or
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, 
height: self.view.frame.height + 20.0)

//Tried setting height constraint
self.view.autoSetDimension(.height, toSize: 270)
```

Comment: What is autoSetDimension? Can you please add the code in the question

Comment: It's never a great idea to use both auto layout and frames.Not that it's not done sometimes, just that it's not a good route to go. In your case? Very hard to say because you haven't (a) given enough code and (b) explained what - and maybe why - you decided to code this way. If you are using auto layout on this view (view controller? again, hard to say with what you've posted) why not just *change* the constraints instead of the frame? EDIT: One last thing you haven't detailed - are you using safe areas? Please, give more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Debug view hierarchy and look for conflicting constraints that might interfere with your height constraint. Also make sure you set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false if you set constraints in code.

Also: if you set your constraint like this in code (apparently you are using PureLayout), that method returns the reference to that height constraint. So if you want to modify it, you need to update the constant value of your constraint, instead of setting a new one.

For any further help you certainly need to share more information.